Memory allocation for a string in C
I tried this method in C because I didn't want to predefine the size of the char * (like char[999]). My main purpose was to create a char * variable to hold a specific word (I dont know how it runs) when I use this code (I did not believed that would work properly while I was coding too) it creates one space of memory for a character. But when I try to print down it prints down the whole string and amazingly when I debug it the console just shows the first character of the string.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    int val;
    char *name;
    struct Node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct Node *list;
    list = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter a string");
    scanf("%s", list->name);
    printf("%s", list->name);
    return 0;
}

I think there is a memory leak or something. Because without any multiplier in the malloc() function I dont believe the compiler would allocate enough memory but I dont know how it saves the letters after the first one that I do not know where.

Type "undefined behavior" in the search bar of your browser.

It just means you are overwriting whatever is after the variable in memory. In the best case it would cause your program to crash so you find your bug.  You got the worst case, which is that your program appears to work.

One way it can appear to work is if the OS happens to allocate memory in 16-byte chunks. Until you enter a longer string.

In the line: list->name=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); you have only allocated enough spaced for a single character. You then try and read a complete string into that space, thus overwiting other information in memory. This will lead to any sort of undefined behaviour. You must allocate enough space for the longest string that you expect to read, and add a restriction in the call to scanf to prevent buffer overflow.

@OldBoy OP knows that: they are asking why it appeared to work.

@WeatherVane Yes, I missed part of what I was supposed to write, and now I cannot edit my post.

In addition to ub: by using malloc() list->next may contain garbage, try using calloc()

When you allocate memory for name with malloc(sizeof(char)), you're allocating exactly one byte of memory, which is enough space for exactly one character. In C, strings are null-terminated, meaning they end with a special null character ('\0'). So, technically, this allocation only has room for an empty string (just the null terminator) .
When you use scanf("%s", list->name) to read a string from the user, scanf does not know that you've only allocated space for one character. It will write the user's input into the memory starting at list->name, overrunning the allocated space if the user inputs anything at all as scanf() always adds a null teminator. This is known as a buffer overflow and is a common source of bugs and security vulnerabilities in C programs.
Despite the buffer overflow, you might find that your program seems to work correctly for small strings. This is because writing past the allocated memory may not immediately cause a crash; it overwrites some other part of your program's memory, which might not be used or checked immediately. However, this is unpredictable and unsafe. The behavior can change with different inputs, compiler optimizations, or even different runs of the same program.
As mention: " because of i didnt wanted to predefine the size of the char* (like char[999]) my main purpose was to create a char* variable to hold a specific word "
Maybe you could write this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1000];

    scanf("%999s", buffer);
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    printf("%d\n", len);

    struct Node *list;
    list = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list->name = (char *)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(list->name, buffer);
    printf("%s\n", list->name);
    return 0;
}

I think it's impossible to predict in advance how many characters a user will type...

There is no standard way to achieve your goal with scanf() alone: scanf("%s", list->name) is inherently unsafe as scanf() will store all matching input to the destination array so any sufficiently long word entered by the user will cause a buffer overflow.
There are two possible solutions:

if you can assume that a maximum length, use a local array to store the input and allocate a copy of the string read:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    int val;
    char *name;
    struct Node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    char buf[1000];
    struct Node *list;

    list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (list == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter a string");
    if (scanf("%999s", buf) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }
    list->name = strdup(buf);
    if (list->name == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot duplicate string\n");
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", list->name);
    free(list->name);
    free(list);
    return 0;
}


Alternately, you can use a function to read a word of arbitrary length, including 0 that scanf() cannot handle.  This approach seems more in line with your goal to read a string from the user as opposed to a word parsed by %s:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    int val;
    char *name;
    struct Node *next;
};

char *get_string(const char *prompt) {
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t size = 16;
    char *buf = malloc(size);
    int c;

    if (!buf)
        return NULL;

    if (prompt) {
        printf("%s: ", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (len + 2 > size) {
            size_t new_size = size + (size >> 1) + 8;
            char *new_buf = realloc(buf, new_size);
            if (new_buf == NULL) {
                free(buf);
                return NULL;
            }
            size = new_size;
            buf = new_buf;
        }
        buf[len++] = c;
    }
    buf[len] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Node *list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (list == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    list->val = 0;
    list->next = NULL;
    list->name = get_string("Enter a string");
    if (list->name == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory\n");
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", list->name);
    free(list->name);
    free(list);
    return 0;
}




Writing into a buffer too small to hold the contents will cause a buffer overflow and trigger undefined behaviour. In practice, unallocated memory or memory allocated for something else will be overwritten. It may appear to work until it does not.
So it must be ensured that the buffer will not be overflowed. No matter how much space is allocated, it cannot be prevented that the user may enter more characters, but scanf() can be instructed to read only a given maximal number of characters.
Having obtained a given number of characters, memory for the characters and the terminating 0 must be allocated. scanf() can also be instructed to provide the number of read characters. Lastly, it must be ensured that scanf() was successful. This is done by checking its return value which equals the number of successful conversions.
All in all:
int main()
{
    char buffer[100+1];  // 100 characters and a terminating 0
    struct Node* list;

    printf("Enter a string (max 100 characters): ");

    unsigned n;  // number of characters read
    if(scanf("%100s%n", buffer, &n) == 1)
    {
        list = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        list->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n+1));
        memcpy(list->name, buffer, n+1);
        printf("%s", list->name);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error reading string
    }
    return 0;
}

Note that scanf() has its limitations. If the user happens to input more than 100 characters, unused characters will be waiting and read next time scanf() is called. There does not seem to be a portable way to avoid that.
